# Is there a way to fill a linear gradient along a diagonal?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to write code that will fill a rectangular region with a gradient that varies along a diagonal of that region.  I had thought that I could play with the direction parameter as follows:

```
context->GradientFillLinear(
   wxrect, 
   get_wx_colour(gradient.front()), 
   get_wx_colour(gradient.back()), 
   wxNORTH | wxEAST);
```

When I do this, the compiler converts the direction subexpression to an int and fails to compile because of a type mismatch.  I suspect that gradients can only be filled horizontally or vertically and this is why the parameter is written expecting an enum value.  Can anyone confirm this suspicion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of wxWidget-3.0.2, the implementation of `GradientFillLinear` eventually calls a specific implementation which looks somewhat like:

```
wxDCImpl::DoGradientFillLinear()
{
  ...
  if ( nDirection == wxEAST || nDirection == wxWEST )
  {
    ...
  }
  else // nDirection == wxNORTH || nDirection == wxSOUTH
  {
    ...
  }
```

So, your suspicion appears to be correct and even if you did manage to somehow coerce the direction as `wxNORTH | wxEAST` in the argument of `GradientFillLinear`, the implementation would not have supported it.

Answer (score 1):

As SleuthEye's answer correctly says, this can't be done directly, but you can always apply a transformation to rotate the horizontal or vertical gradient by 45 degrees.